# EF code First: Database initializers vs. database migration, and use of Configuration.Seed vs. DropCreateDatabaseAlways.Seed methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I hope I got some attention on this, as I posted 2 questions that got no answers sate my curiosity: [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39548257/ef-seed-of-migrations-configuration-vs-seed-of-dropcreatedatabasealways) and the [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39551770/why-doesnt-dropcreatedatabasealways-drop-the-database-when-the-model-changes)

I want to know in which case database initializers work:

- If the database schema changes from the code (i.e. property added to
  the    entity, deleted or modified)
- Or the database itself changes (i.e. column added, deleted or
  modified) from the server
- Or if the data changes (data added, deleted or modified) and still
  have to use migration along with initializers to handle changes on
  the database schema.

Also if I enabled both initializers and
   migration in my code, which Seed method will be used to initialize data?

Comment: Am I the only person who's ever been aware of these differences?! That's feel good actually!

Comment: I suppose you could do both, but the way I normally describe it is use one of the Drop initializers for early development where you don't care to retain the database contents. Yes, there is an initializer seed() that runs only when the database is created. At some point you are not going to want to lose the data in the non-lookup tables and should switch to migrations (or another method like database projects). Changes on the database side should be avoided in Code First. https://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Comment: See my link regarding your last question - initializer seed only runs when database created, migration seed runs after every update-database.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I found your blog yesterday while Googling about these issues, It's really useful. But I have a question, I'm looking for your help. Does initializers work if I added a record in the code, I tried doing this but i get an error about busy database, does that mean that it can't seed and add data (manually) at the same time?

Comment: I restarted VS, and it works again,